# Unexpected margin using Arial font in bold

Tags: css, windows, fonts

While using Arial font in bold, an unexpected margin (just ~ 1 px) appears from the left side.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/be2EW/1/

HTML:

```
<b>ABC</b> <br />
<b>STU</b>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

It works fine on Mac OS X based browsers, but not on Windows.

Is there somebody who has ever had a similar problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is related to the font-rendering of the Arial font, not CSS.

Comment: @kleinfreund I understand, but is there a fix for it?

Comment: @ozgur This is not related. This has nothing to with CSS, it's a font-rendering issue. user: There won't be real _fix_, but possible hacky workarounds. But I don't think this is really needed. Is this a real problem for your?

Comment: What margin? Please describe the directly observable phenomenon you are re ferring. Also explain why you think it is margin. Boldface glyphs are different from regular glyphs, so it is hardly *unexpected* that some bold glyphs may *look* like having a small amount of space on their left (or right) side.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have added a link to a screenshot in my main post. Is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this is not related to CSS, but rather to font rendering. Different browsers render fonts differently. Even the same browser will render a certain font differently on different platforms, as you have mentioned yourself by comparing Mac OS X based browsers with Windows.

Solutions you could try:

- Use CSS to re-position the text
- Change to a different font
- Remove bold
- Create a static image (not the best option)

Alternatively you could check out CSS3 Fonts Module: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/

Keep in mind that tags such as `font-stretch`, `font-size-adjust`, `letter-spacing`, `text-rendering` are not supported on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its unavoidable.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/be2EW/3/

This occurs most notably at larger sizes as the fiddle above illustrates. Unfortunately your options are very limited. You could try some hacks with letter-spacing but this would be a massively convoluted solution.

Obviously the best course of action would be to use a more uniform typeface.

```
<b>A</b><br />
<b>B</b><br />
<b>C</b><br />
<b>D</b><br />
<b>E</b><br />
<b>F</b><br />
<b>G</b><br />
<b>H</b><br />
<b>I</b><br />
<b>J</b><br />
<b>K</b><br />
<b>L</b><br />
<b>M</b><br />
<b>N</b><br />
<b>O</b><br />
<b>P</b><br />
<b>Q</b><br />
<b>R</b><br />
<b>S</b><br />
<b>T</b><br />
<b>U</b><br />
<b>V</b><br />
<b>W</b><br />
<b>X</b><br />
<b>Y</b><br />
<b>Z</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a margin at all, or anything that would depend on CSS. The spacing on the left of “U” in Arial bold, for example, is part of the glyph itself. This can be seen in a glyph editor: the glyph appears inside its bounding box so that there is empty space on either side of it. Such spacing often prevents glyphs from touching each other. In “S”, the effect is smaller, and the reason why there seems to be some space on the left is mostly the shape of the letter.

In hardcore typesetting, such issues are sometimes handled by fine-tuning the horizontal placement of letters. It is possible, but clumsy and not common, to do such things in CSS, too. For example, you could wrap a line of text in an element and set the following declarations on it:

```
position: relative; left: -1px;
```

This might sometimes be reasonable for display texts like headlines.